# Create a group on facebook using graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a Facebook group using graph API. 
i have more search on Google and also Facebook developers section for this but no luck.
Advice me if this is possible and how i do this.
Thanks

Comment: @Govind i already seen this asked on 09 and facebook have more changes after this so if you have any answer for this

Comment: look like you you didn't check whole thread, just check Kevin Liang's response.

Comment: have you read answer please advice me some code how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if this possible.

There might be security flow if they allow this operation.

Comment: is there any link or description for explaining this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/
Only create Post, event, link available

Comment: thanks i have already seen this but there is no description for describe this that this is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Good Question, but unfortunately there is no such option available with Facebook Graph API at this moment.

With Graph API you can do following actions

1. Create Post
2. Create Link
3. Create Event

More actions are described here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

I hope in future Facebook allows developer to create group also, but for now; you can not.

Comment: any other api who support this feature?

Comment: I'm sorry but NO. There is no other API from facebook that supports this action.